# Fluent UI Blazor component FluentDatePicker does not open its calendar

Tags: blazor, fluent-ui

I'm new to blazor and to the *fluent ui library* for blazor. I think they are both awesome.
Now I have this problem with the *FluentDatePicker* control in my blazor server application. It just does not open its calendar when I click the icon on the right side of the control.

I read on a similar question here that maybe it has something to do with css styles, and the solutions was to add the line:

```
<link href="{PROJECT_NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to the `_Host.cshtm` file.

Now I'm using net version 8 and I suppose the file is now *App.razor* and it already has the line, as I used the blazor fluent ui template from visual studio to create my blazor server application.

I have been looking for a file like `contab_blazor2.styles.css` and can't find one.
Where is that file? And has another developer experienced this kind of problem and maybe has a solution for it?

Thanks ...

Comment: About the `{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css` file, check: [CSS isolation bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling).

Comment: You included: `builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();` in `program.cs`?
`

Comment: "my blazor server application" needs clarification. What version, (and for 8+) what rendermode?

Comment: Well, I just found the next day that the FluentDatePicker was working as expected. It opened its calendar when I clicked the icon on the right. I have been working with the fluent controls for five or six days already, but I haven't tried out the FluentDatePicker. Now, I refreshed the browser page many times, just knowing that it could be a css issue, but with no results. And, I still don't know where the contab_blazor2.styles.css file is located.

Comment: DimitrisMaragkos: thanks for the link. I should have known that since the beginning. BrianP: yes, it was there all the time. Henk: it is InteractiveServer. Thanks to all. Everything seems to work fine already.